# Is there a way to put the output of perfmon get-counter to sql table via power-shell?

Tags: sql, windows, powershell, performancecounter, perfmon

I have developed below code to put the output of get-counter from perfmon in sql table but i have used -Continuous option so this will give me data for infinite time and data only gets inserted after never ending loop break ? actual requirement is i want to insert data continua sally? is there a way to achieve this ?

```
$Event = Get-counter -Counter “\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length” -SampleInterval 1  -computername sqldemo1,sqldemo2 -Continuous  
$Events += $Event
  
        Function WriteServiceInfo
        {          
    param($TimeCreated,$CounterSamples)

          $InsertResults = @"
    INSERT INTO [DBA].[dbo].[t](Timestamp,CounterSamples)
    VALUES ('$TimeCreated','$CounterSamples')
"@     
      
    SQLCMD -b -S SQLDEMO1 -d DBA -Q $InsertResults    
 }

 for($i=0; $i -lt $Events.Count; $i++)
{
    writeServiceInfo $Events[$i].TimeCreated $Events[$i].CounterSamples
}
```

Comment: You'd use a loop, but forever loops can be a issue depending on what you are doing. So a dp/while or do/until is what you'll normally see suggested. Yet if it were me, I'd spend the time taking a more elegant solution. Especially since SQL is in the use case.

Comment: @postanote Thanks for your inputs, can you suggest other solution please ? i am capturing this data for creating backdated dashboard reports  from multiple sql instances of servers. Also one more thing when i remove -Continuos its putting bad data (wrong) in table